# Why is the scale for extrude faces along normals not the same as the world scale?

Tags: extrude

I am trying to extrude the exterior edges of an object by exactly 0.5m.
I can do this, but I have select extrude along normals and type 0.125
When I type 0.5 instead, it extrudes by 2m.
Why is it multiplying by 8???

Comment: Is your object scale maybe not applied? Does it show _Scale_ 1 for all axis in _Object Mode_ or something else (for example 4)? By the way, it's multiplying with 4.

Comment: Yep!  That was it!  Thanks!  (Also math is hard :P)